# Change columns ordering in desktop view

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/) framework.

Can anyone tell me how to re-order the foundation grid.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 large-12 large-push-12 columns">
      Mobile top. Desktop bottom.
   </div>

   <div class="small-12 large-12 large-pull-12 columns">
      Mobile bottom. Desktop top.
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is in desktop layout: the `large-push-12` and `large-pull-12` aren't working and the grid isn't re-ordered.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Show the rest of the code, like CSS...

Comment: i'm using foundation framework, it's quite common

Answer (score 0):

You can't use source ordering concept in Foundation for Full width columns.

Please check below code block for understand to Foundation source ordering concept.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-5 small-push-7 medium-7 medium-push-5 columns">7</div>
  <div class="small-7 small-pull-5 medium-5 medium-pull-7 columns">5, last</div>
</div>
```

Ref. Link - https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html